# Why is ServerName not having any effect?

Tags: apache, virtualhost

I have several sites configured as VirtualHost. All of them are running on the same system, same IP address. I want apache to redirect requests to one or another VirtualHost based on the DNS. That is why I am using [ServerName](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#servername). Quoting:

> If you are using name-based virtual hosts, the ServerName inside a
>    section specifies what hostname must appear in the
>   request's Host: header to match this virtual host.

This is how my Virtual Host configuration looks like:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *>

    ServerName my.dns.net

    ....

</VirtualHost>
```

But apache, instead of maching the requests as per DNS, is just redirecting requests to the first VirtualHost defined.

- Why is that?
- What can I do to force apache to do exact DNS matching?

Comment: Do you have all different servernames set in your DNS/hostsfile? That's a must!

Comment: Sure, sure. The servernames are active.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following Directive tells apache that you are going to use name-based virtual hosts.

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
```

If you look at the example in the apache docs:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html

You can see that it is defined before the VirtualHosts. That make sense, because until that Directive is processed, Apache doesn't know that you are going to use name-based virtual hosts.

It is important to understand the order in which Apache processes the conf files. If you look in your apache2.conf, you will see this code:

```
# Include module configuration:
Include mods-enabled/*.load
Include mods-enabled/*.conf

# Include all the user configurations:
Include httpd.conf

# Include ports listing
Include ports.conf

(...)

# Include generic snippets of statements
Include conf.d/

# Include the virtual host configurations:
Include sites-enabled/
```

Therefore, the processing order is:

apache2.conf -> apache modules -> httpd.conf -> ports.conf -> any .conf file present in  /etc/apache2/conf.d/ -> finally (in alphabetical order) your VirtualHosts conf files.

In your code you have defined the Directive in your VirtualHost conf file, but you might have other VirtualHosts before that one. Therefore, as Apache reads the VirtualHosts confs files in alfabethical order, it might read another VirtualHost conf file before parsing the "NameVirtualHost *:80" directive, and therefore it won't read the following VirtualHosts conf files.

The solution is to define that directive anywhere before the virtualhosts conf files. I think (although I am not 100% sure) that in Ubuntu Server the standard way is to define that line in /etc/apache2/ports.conf, which as explained before is read before all the virtualhosts in /etc/apache2/sites-avalaible. Therefore, Apache will know that you have ServerNames and will try every virtualhost before falling back to the default (first) one.